# Accepting a GZIP file with NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express, gzip

I have a service which takes in a GZIP file from a client, the client has the header set:

```
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
```

The code that is accepting the incoming data is just the ubiquitous code that I've found on the net:

```
var postbody = [];

req.on('data', function (chunk){ 
    postbody.push(chunk);
}); 

req.on('end',function(){ 
    var result = postbody.join('');
    etc...
```

The problem is, when I look at the file, specifically using linux: file myFile it says it is of type data. No longer gzip. Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chunks you are getting are buffers, not strings. You should do:

```
var result = Buffer.concat(postbody);
```

To get the final gzip.